# The AdminUI Option

Tags: jhipster

I always selected the adminUI option for a JHipster project. Today, I don't select it for an unusual purpose. Its web page structure looks the same as those projects with adminUI. And the generated code under the webapp directory looks to have the same structure as those with adminUI. So, what are the differences with the adminUI selection other than the npm command of bringing up the UI and fewer menu items under administration?

Comment: What authentication mechanism did you choose? For JWT and session, you'll have user management in the admin UI, as well as metrics. For OAuth, there will be no user management since you're expected to do that at your identity provider.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for your info. The project uses JWT for authentication and I do see user management under the administration menu. I thought the adminUI is the default front-end. It certainly isn't the case.

Comment: You can use `--skip-client` if you want no frontend.